# Zapier Webhook to DocuSign sign document

Tags: json, docusignapi, zapier

Has anyone got a Zapier webhook zap to document signing request working? When I try it, it just gives me the template to sign.

Another example gives me simply "400 Bad Request".

TIA,

Comment: This is worth reaching out to Zapier support for, they should be able to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Why do you think I'm here?!